# FTP connect with Windows powershell after setting the firewall port and passive-mode checked

Tags: iis, ftp, ftp-client, filezilla, windows-firewall

I have encountered some issues when clients connect to the server using FTP.

Specifically:

When the client uses File Explorer to open ftp://192.XXX.XXX.XXX, they can browse the files successfully,

as shown below:

[image]

When using FileZilla to connect, the client can also see the list of files successfully,

as shown below:

[image]

FileZilla is configured to use passive mode and other setting
by default, as indicated below:

[image]

However, when attempting to connect using PowerShell,

after entering the credentials and inputting the command to view the file list

, the following error message appears:

`150 opening ascii mode data connection`

[image]

**Here are the steps that have been checked:**

1.Firewall input rule settings on the server:

Ports 21 and 1024-65535 are open.
Additional FTP server input rule settings:

Specific ports are open, as shown below:

[image]

2.The client's connection is also configured to use passive mode by default

, as shown below:

[image]

I would like to inquire if there are any other settings that need to be confirmed.

The main purpose of this question is that I intend to

use a batch script to execute a scheduled task for file transfer.

If there is additional information that needs to be provided

please let me know.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl  Thank you very much. I was surprised to find out that PowerShell doesn't default to passive mode. After setting "quote pasv" and adding an input rule to the client's firewall to open the corresponding port, file transfer is now successful.

Comment: Good. Note that `quote pasv` has no effect (my answer even says that), it actually should break your code. + It's not about PowerShell – you are using plain on Windows `ftp` commandline client.